# How to assert an attribute's rendered value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm new to [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and looking at [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) as a potential unit testing solution.  However, I've found it surprisingly difficult to find out how to simply assert a rendered attribute value in a `ReactComponent`.  I'm not sure if this is because the usual practice is to not render and see the actual value, or if I've just not found a good example yet.

So, here is what I'm working with:

**Label component:**

```
var Label = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if (this.props.targetName) {
            return (
                <label htmlFor="{this.props.targetName}">{this.props.content}</label>
            );
        }
        return (
                <label>{this.props.content}</label>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Label;
```

**Jest test:**

```
describe('Label sub component', function() {
    var Label = require('../../../views/label');
    it('has the correct target element name', function() {
        var labelDocument = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
                <Label targetName="foobar" content="Upload Files:"/>
        );
        var label = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(labelDocument, 'label');
        expect(label.getDOMNode().getAttribute('for')).toEqual('foobar');  // actually returns {this.props.targetName}
    });
});
```

So, as you can see, I'm not certain about the expect assertion here.  I'd like to expect that the value `foobar` is rendered in the correct element.  Then, I can make sure that the `props` binding is correct. `label` is a `ReactComponent` and I see many properties and methods available.  What is the best way to see and test for the actual value that would be rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a syntax error. This line:

```
<label htmlFor="{this.props.targetName}">{this.props.content}</label>
```

Should be:

```
<label htmlFor={this.props.targetName}>{this.props.content}</label>
```

Notice that there's no quotes around the attribute value.

Also note that your `label` variable is a React component instance, which has a `props` property that you can use instead of looking it up on the DOM node.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is my issue.  Seems strange that the "syntax issue" renders fine in a browser.

Comment: Well, it's not a syntax error really, my mistake for phrasing it that way. It's just valid code inside a string, and there's no way for the Javascript engine to know that it's code and not a string (remember that everything inside { and } in JSX is just Javascript).

Comment: Thank you. I guess that makes sense.  There *must* be some way for react to know, however, because it renders fine in the browser :).  If there was no way to know then I'd expect to see `{this.props.targetName}` rendered.  I've now checked and this was indeed causing the issue.  So, thanks very much for your help.