# How do I get an attribute of an element nested in a React component using Jest and/or Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test to see whether an image has properly loaded in a React app. I have decided to check the `src` attribute of the `img` element nested within the React component. I want to use the Jest testing framework and, if needed, the Enzyme testing utility.

By digging through the `Object.keys` of a shallow React test component, I was able to come up with the following solution. The line I'm uncertain about is indicated with the asterisks.

```
import React     from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import App       from './App';

it('should have the logo image', () => {
  const app = shallow(<App />);
  const img = app.find('img');
  const src = img.node.props.src; // ******
  expect(src).toBe('logo.svg');
});
```

This solution *does* work but it seems a little convoluted (it requires a property of a property of a property of a wrapper) and seems somewhat obscure (I can't easily find clear instructions for this online). So, is this the correct/simplest way to do this?

- If so, where is the documentation?
- If not, how else should/could I be doing this? e.g. Is there some ready-made `getAttribute` or `retrieveProp` method, etc. in Enzyme? Is there a better way of doing this using something else instead of Enzyme, e.g. `react-addons-test-utils`?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29882520/5218951) about React element attributes doesn't seem to quite answer it for me even though the poster there also indicates having a hard time finding documentation about asserting a rendered attribute value. A number of other questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40858984/5218951), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39854162/5218951) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40466134/5218951)) deal with React/Jest/Enzyme but don't deal with retrieving attribute values.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

After some digging, I found the following. The indicated line in the question:

```
const src = img.node.props.src;
```

can be simplified to the following:

```
const src = img.prop('src');
```

The documentation can be found [here](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/prop.html).

If someone knows of a non-Enzyme way of doing this, I'd still be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: enzyme has deprecated `.node` method and encourages to use `.getElement` method instead.

Comment: I used something like this:
`mount(<MyComponent/>).find().prop('src')`

Answer (score 24):

For me, it worked as below

`expect(companySelect.find('input').props()["disabled"]).toBe(true)`

`props()` returns an object having all the attributes of the selector and then it can be browsed as an object.

Hope this helps too....

https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/props.html

Comment: `.props()["disabled"]` and `.toBe(true)` can be simplified to `expect(companySelect.find('input').prop('disabled')).toBeTruthy()`

Comment: In my case `props` was not a function and I had to use `props["aria-label"]`

Answer (score 15):

The [@testing-library/jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) library provides a custom matcher [`toHaveAttribute`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveattribute). After extending `expect` clause

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
```

we can assert like

```js
const rect = document.querySelector('[data-testid="my-rect"]')
expect(rect).toHaveAttribute('width', '256')
```

Answer (score 13):

With React [Test Utilities](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html):

```
it('should have the logo image', () => 
  const app = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<App/>);
  var image = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(app, 'img');
  expect(image.getDOMNode().getAttribute('src')).toEqual('logo.svg');
});
```

Enzyme tests looks much cleaner.

Comment: The Enzyme `.prop` accessor does not inspect the emitted HTML. It simply ensures that the prop was fed into the component under test. `getDOMNode().getAttribute` is what you need.

Answer (score 13):

For me this worked

```
expect(component.find('button').props().disabled).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Except that the error message this one would throw would be less friendly (Expected undefined to be truthy) vs (Expected elem to haveAttribute disabled)

Answer (score 2):

.node is not working After some hard work, I found the following is 100% related to answer for above question

```
  const src = img.getElement().props.src;
```